# Facebook not showing my text being shared in android.

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am trying to share some text using **`ACTION_SEND`** intent. Everywhere , my text is being shared like WhatsApp and Google Plus. But FB is not showing my text. Here is my code.

```
   String myText= "My String to share";
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
   shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myText);
   shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
   shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Comment: You need to use Facebook SDK for sharing. As Facebook will not allow sharing through Intent.

Comment: Can you guide me a lil about Facebook SDK and sharing...

Comment: Sure, I will post my answer in a while.

Comment: Ok, m looking forward to that.

Comment: Have u checked the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to download the Facebook SDK. Go through the following link to download the latest version.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Now you need to check the related docs available on the same site. For example first of all you have to check whether Facebook is present in the users device or not. Then if its present, you have to build a login module through Facebook. Here, I am adding the code to share any information through Facebook SDK only.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity) mContext)
                .setLink("Website link for app")
                .setDescription(shareText)
                .setName("App_Name")
                .build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
                dismissDialog();
```

Also, I am just sharing some description here. You can check other attributes also as per your requirement.
Hope it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Yes I am trying. I have a question. In ".setLink()" mehtod, whats the link? the link of my app on facebook?

Comment: Its can be a link to your apps Facebook page.

Comment: I have done this and its working but it still making it as a link. What i need is only a text.

Comment: use .setDescription() method mentioned above. Here you can share the text.

Comment: If you have achieved what you want then please accept the answer :)